# Missing father's obligations on sons (Kiddushin 29)

Tags: talmud-gemara, mitzvah

According to the Mishna in Kiddushin 29, backed by the Braitah (in place), father's Mitzvos (definition not clear) upon his son(s) are only the follows:

> 1. Circumcise
> 2. Redeem the firstborn
> 3. Teach Torah
> 4. Marry him off
> 5. Teach him a profession
> 6. (some say) Teach him to swim.

This list seems to lack a couple of important obligations discussed elsewhere, such as **Chinuch for Mitzvos** (*see Mishnah in Succah about one's obligation to provide his sons with 4 Minim and a Succah)* or **Reciting the Aggadah** *(mentioned numerous times in Torah and Rambam's explicit Mitzvah*) or **Maintaining a healthy lifestyle** (*Rambam's Yilchot Deot*). There are also monetary obligations, such as Takkanat Ushah.

1. Can you think of additional Mitzvos missing?
2. What can be a reason for such a partial list?

Comment: Isn't the list a list of things that are *specifically* on the father to do?

Comment: @Uber_Chacham No, it seems that a father takes a precedence, but they are not limited to fathers. See Milah, Pidyon, Talmud Torah.