# Is one obligated to do Bar Mitzvah if one's father didn't do it for him?

Tags: halacha, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

Braitah in [Kiddushin 29a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.29a.1?lang=bi):

> תנינא להא דת"ר האב חייב בבנו: למולו ולפדותו וללמדו תורה ולהשיאו אשה וללמדו אומנות וי"א אף להשיטו במים...:
>
> ... the Sages taught in a Baraita: A father is obligated with regard to his son to circumcise him, and to redeem him if he is a firstborn son who must be redeemed by payment to a priest, and to teach him Torah, and to marry him to a woman, and to teach him a trade.

To continue [what-things-are-done-differently-for-an-adult-circumcision](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94427/what-things-are-done-differently-for-an-adult-circumcision/94428) and [missing-fathers-obligations-on-sons](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90290/missing-fathers-obligations-on-sons-kiddushin-29)questions, if one's father didn't do a Bar Mitzvah for his son, is the latter obligated to do that for himself?

That would include Torah reading, the Seudah and more. Oh, also getting presents, I assume.

Answer (score 5):

[R. Moshe Feinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein) wrote the following in a responsum:

**[Igrot Moshe O.C. 1:104](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&pgnum=170)**

> ואי איישר חילי הייתי מבטל במדינתנו גם סדר הבר מצוה של הבנים שכידוע לא
>   הביא זה שום איש לקרבו לתורה ולמצות ואף לא את הבר מצוה אף לא לשעה אחת
>   ואדרבה בהרבה מקומות מביא זה לחלול שבת ועוד איסורים
>
> And if I had the strength I would cancel in our country even the Bar
>   Mitzvah for sons, which as is known has never brought any man to come
>   closer to Torah and to mitzvot, nor even the Bar Mitzvah [boy
>   himself], even for one moment. Just the opposite! In many places it
>   leads to Sabbath violation and other prohibitions.

So, is the son obligated to have a Bar Mitzvah if the father never made one for him? It would seem that R. Feinstein would say that not only is he not obligated, it should probably be discouraged.